# How to change the Default text size in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have three text sizes in Windows 7:

- Smaller 100%
- Medium 125%
- Larger 150%

On our VMs, Smaller 100% is listed as "default" regardless of whether it's selected or not.  On my local work machine, Medium 125% is listed as "default" regardless of whether it's selected or not.  In the help file on both machines, 100% is listed as the default.

I'm trying to configure my local machine as Smaller 100% (default).  How do I do this?

I've matched the themings and resolutions of my local machine to the VM, but my machine is still at 125% for default, and 100% for in-use.

I am trying to rule out some font rendering issues in Windows 7.  The font sizes look great on the VMs, but not locally.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click Desktop
- Click Personalization
- Click Window Color
- Click Advanced Appearance Settings
- For Item, use the pull down arrow > select Message Box
- Under font > change the size to 9 > click OK

Found on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-defaults-text-size-to-medium-125-how-can/46ec13bc-4157-4aca-a896-f1a99bdf5f55).

Comment: This did not work.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Did you take a look at your DPI settings for the font size? http://www.uniquetipsonline.com/how-to-change-default-font-size-in-windows-7/

Comment: Yes I did, and they're identical on both machines

Comment: I did find a difference in HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts\LogPixels -- I'm wondering if this isn't getting updated propertly due to corporate restrictions on stuff

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, this is what I have found out so far:

```
125%:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Courier 10,12,15"="COURF.FON"
"MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SERIFF.FON"
"MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SSERIFF.FON"
"Small Fonts"="SMALLF.FON"
"Small Fonts (120)"="SMALLF.FON"

100%:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Courier 10,12,15"="COURE.FON"
"MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SERIFE.FON"
"MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"="SSERIFE.FON"
"Small Fonts"="SMALLE.FON"
"Small Fonts (120)"="SMALLF.FON"
```

Filename ending with "F" is big font. I had to change those values to be able to display correctly older Delphi software.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)